# How do I add a jar-file to Ant for a NetBeans Java Web App project so that it gets build?

Tags: java, ant, glassfish

I am trying to set up an automatic build system with command line ant.

Using glassFish 4.1 and Netbeans 8.0.2

**My command line build I have the following command:**

C:\java\NetBeans 8.0.2\extide\ant\bin>ant -f \Java\Temp\myproject\build.xml -Dnb.internal.action.name=build -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=\Java\Temp\myproject\ -Duser.properties.file=C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\build.properties -Dj2ee.server.home=C:\java\glassfish4\GLASSFISH\ dist

And this is the last part of my output:

```
[javac] C:\Java\Temp\crmparts\src\java\freedom\bytecode\service\CrmPartsServiceA.java:10: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[javac] import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
[javac]                   ^
[javac] C:\Java\Temp\crmparts\src\java\freedom\bytecode\service\CrmPartsServiceA.java:11: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[javac] import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
[javac]                   ^
[javac] C:\Java\Temp\crmparts\src\java\freedom\bytecode\service\CrmPartsServiceA.java:12: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[javac] import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
[javac]                   ^
[javac] C:\Java\Temp\crmparts\src\java\freedom\bytecode\service\CrmPartsServiceA.java:13: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[javac] import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] C:\Java\Temp\crmparts\src\java\freedom\bytecode\service\CrmPartsServiceA.java:14: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[javac] import javax.ws.rs.GET;
```

I have no experience with the "Ant", so I have searched and found a lot about it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get this library added so that the project gets properly build on ant.

I do not use maven or jenkins. My problem is only in those libraries, and the library is already added to projects/libraries.

**My question is: how do I my that the Java "ant" compiler does not complain about missing packages (i.e. missing jar files)?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my Dj2ee.server.home parameter. I made the correction and it worked.